# Multiple annotations found at this line

Tags: android, android-layout

Multiple annotations found at this line:   - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.onyourcar.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: Please post the complete XML

Comment: the error does not seem to be in your textview, please post the rest

Comment: Actually I am a self learner and what I am trying to do is creating a new id so I can see the effect on the application.

Comment: Do you close this FrameLayout tag? Is that your whole xml content?

Comment: Yes, This is my whole xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default texview is like so

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theTextViewIdHere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

And try to use a relative/linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you would like to use FrameLayout hit google for example code

My first guess at your problem was the last line of 'tools:context' try removing that line. In case this does not work post your entire XML file.

Hope this will help.

Comment: If I remove the "tools:context" I am having an err: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: I also suggest you need to google what the difference is between a relative and a linear layout.